# Displays a menu based on permissions in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

there is no right to access the menu **home, profile, gallery, contact us**.
I have 2 types of user that is the **administrator** and **operator**. eg the **administrator** just the **home**, **profile**, and **contact us** menu to see. while in the **operator**, just the **home** and **profile** menu are visible. how to differentiate the permissions on codeigniter?

please help me, thank you :)

Comment: Use ascl library and give role types

Comment: can you give me a link to download it?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/213845

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is provide a profile id to differentiate the users. For example for Admin 1 and for Operator user 2. When you are displaying menu in the view file put some conditions on your menu display using profile id.

Note save profile id in session data with user data.

Answer (score 0):

Having different user types works if you never envision having more than two types or people that need one admin permission but not another. A better, or rather more future proof, way to do it is through roles.

Create a roles table with your different roles in it, for your use now you would have Admin and User roles. Then you create a join table that would hold the RoleId and the UserId. When a user logs in you create a session variable and populate it with an array of the different roles they hold, then when you have a specific page that requires protection you simply have to check that array for the required permission.

As an example say you have a business site, you require user logins, a main admin login, a sales login and a warehouse login. Let's say for the sake of argument that sales and warehouse need the ability to edit products, but the warehouse shouldn't be allowed to edit prices. You could of course assign different user types and then check for those user types when a page is loaded but the more and more permissions required the messier that gets. With the roles you assign warehouse and sales people the product permission role and only sales get the price editing permission.

As I said if you only ever require two separate user types with two distinct sets of permissions, role based authentication is probably overkill. But that being said it can't hurt to plan and build for a situation where you find you're going to need more.